# composite primary key that is also a foreign key that references a primary composite key

Tags: mysql, syntax, foreign-keys, primary-key, composite-key

Is it possible to do a composite primary key that is also a foreign key that references a primary composite key?

For example, say i have the table Person with a composite key:

```
create table Person(
id varchar(50) not null,
nationality varchar(50) not null,
PRIMARY KEY (id, nationality)
);
```

and i want to make a table called worker that has a primary key that is also a foreign key (like a specialization of a composite key), for example like this (although it doesnt work):

```
create table worker(
id varchar(50) not null,
nationality varchar(50) not null,
PRIMARY KEY (id, nationality),
FOREIGN KEY (id) REFERENCES Person (id),
FOREIGN KEY (nationality) REFERENCES Person (nationality),
);
```

How would i go about doing this?

Answer (score 0):

To make a foreign key composite, it should have more than one column.

You made two foreign keys with one column each, not a compound foreign key.

```
create table worker(
id varchar(50) not null,
nationality varchar(50) not null,
PRIMARY KEY (id, nationality),
FOREIGN KEY (id, nationality) REFERENCES Person (id, nationality)
);
```